# Difference between Exactly/At Least? (Combination with repetition)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**What is the main difference between exactly and at least?**
I'm having a hard time figuring out how to start these two problems because of that. If anyone can give me insight on how to start each problem, but not answer them, that would be greatly appreciated!

If an inventory of 30 batteries is selected at random from the eight different types, what is the probability that at least four A76 batteries will be included?

If an inventory of 30 batteries is selected at random from the eight different types, what is the probability that exactly four A76 batteries will be included?

Comment: at least 4 means "4, 5, 6 , 7, ... or 30" and exactly 4 means "4"

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_k$ be the number of batteries of type $k$, where $x_1$ is the number of type A76.

> If an inventory of $30$ batteries is selected at random from the eight different types, what is the probability that at least four A76 batteries will be included?

The denominator is the total number of ways $30$ batteries can be selected is the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8 = 30 \tag{1}$$
in the nonnegative integers.

For the numerator, we need to solve equation 1 in the nonnegative integers subject to the restriction that $x_1 \geq 4$.

**Hint:**  Since $x_1 \geq 4$, then $y_1 = x_1 - 4$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $y_1 + 4$ for $x_1$ in equation 1 gives 
$$y_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8 = 26$$

> If an inventory of $30$ batteries is selected at random from the eight different types, what is the probability that exactly four A76 batteries will be included?

The denominator is the same as above.

For the numerator, substitute $4$ for $x_1$ to obtain 
$$x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8 = 26$$
Again, you need to determine the number of solutions in the nonnegative integers.